# Is this bad technique for PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I have been using PDO prepared statements for a couple personal projects.

I have been doing them like follows:

```
$1 = 1;
$2 = 2;
$3 = 3;
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($1, $2, $3));
```

It seems to work fine but I want to know if there is any security issues doing it like this?

Is it even still considered a prepared statement?

Comment: Why shouldn't this be a prepared statement?

Comment: Even though you're using prepared statements, you need to also think about XSS injection.

Comment: Good point Fred, I havent really looked into that yet i will do now.

Comment: regarding loading array values into `->execute()` no theres no security issues to it regarding sql injection, those values are still bound to those placeholders you have set. the setup you have right there is good. there are pros and cons also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still a prepared statement, there aren't any specific security concerns from doing that.

However, you may consider using bound parameters for more complex queries, or where there are a greater number of parameters. It'll be easier for you and future maintainers of the code to visually parse.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (:f1, :f2, :f3)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':f1', $f1);
$stmt->bindParam(':f2', $f2);
$stmt->bindParam(':f3', $f3);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Great i will try to practice the techinique you provided. its good to know that i am still on the right track.